# Do I have to pay visa fees again for a new DS 160 form?

Tags: visas, usa, fees-and-charges

When I arrived at the embassy, I was told that I have not completed my DS 160 form. I returned home and tried to complete it but I could not retrieve the file from the internet. I have completed another new DS 160 form now, do I still need to pay the visa fees? I have already paid for my previous form.